# how to restore my system to factory settings

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, system-restore

I have sony vaio with default win 7 and a recovery partition. I have installed ubuntu in other partition. How do I recover the system to factory settings now. The default alt+f10 is not working anymore for recovery option.

Comment: Sometimes you have the option to create recovery DVD from within the Windows. Have you checked if that option is available?

Comment: Why don't you install a fresh windows, it's better anyway (If you have all the drivers).